# Добавление класса с параметром scroll и удаление в зависимости от условия

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Есть фильтр, задача в зависимости от кол-ва дочерних элементов в блоке, добавлять или удалять css класс, помогите найти ошибку

```
function refresh_pharmacy_detail(){
        var detail = $("#response");
        var pharms = get_filtered_pharmacies();
        if(pharms){
            var detailData = "";
            pharms.forEach(function(el){
                detailData += get_tpl(el);
            });
            detail.html(detailData);
            var child = $(".aside_adress").each(function () {
                          $(this).find('div').length;
                        });
            if(child.length > 9){
                child.addClass('.aside_adress_scroll');
            }else{
                child.removeClass('.aside_adress_scroll');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: добавь html и css тоже

Comment: как добавляете дочерние элементы?

Comment: [mcve] добавьте